# Why do I need to add const to the argument?

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, g++, gtkmm

I have this function :

```
void
SpookyBoy( bool Troublemaker, const Glib::ustring& name, HorrorPunkBand& band );
```

if I remove the word `const` I got this error :

```
 no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘const char [5]’ to ‘Glib::ustring&’
```

I just wonder what does the compiler, can someone explains to me why with the word `const` the compiler can cast ?

---

even if I have to admit the two questions are similar for someone who already knows the answer (at *fortiori*), but certainly not for someone who does not know yet the answwer (at *priori*).

Comment: Does your function declaration really look like that? According to the error message the `ustring` parameter is apparently declared as `const Glib::ustring& name`, i.e. as a reference.

Comment: @AnT yes you right, I forget the & +1 to you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why const for implicit conversion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895647/why-const-for-implicit-conversion)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are apparently calling your function with a string literal as an argument

```
SpookyBoy(..., "1234", ...);
```

The compiler can implicitly convert the string literal (which in this case has type `const char [5]`) to type `Glib::ustring`. But the result of that implicit conversion is a *temporary object*. In C++ language only *const* lvalue references can be bound to temporary objects. Non-const references cannot be bound to temporary objects.

Without that `const` in function declaration you'd have to call your function as

```
Glib::ustring name("1234");
SpookyBoy(..., name, ...);
```

i.e. by explicitly introducing a named object of `Glib::ustring` type and passing it as an argument.

P.S. See also [Why const for implicit conversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895647/why-const-for-implicit-conversion)